# React, typescript - No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yukxyk?file=users%2FUsers.tsx)

It's a simple app using the GitHub api to display uses and there avatars.

I have a Users component that lists the users data in the state.

This uses a UserItem component to display the data from the state.

The example here actually works but the one I have locally doesn't

I get an error on thr UserItem component in the Users component.

The error is

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<IUserItemProps>): UserItem', gave the following error.
    Type '{ user: { id: string; login: string; avatar_url: string; html_url: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<IUserItemProps>': login, avatar_url, html_url
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: IUserItemProps, context?: any): UserItem', gave the following error.
    Type '{ user: { id: string; login: string; avatar_url: string; html_url: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<IUserItemProps>': login, avatar_url, html_url
```

I know this is a typescript issue but how can I update the interface to stop this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, you're trying to use an object with a `user` property where an object with `login`, `avatar_url`, and `html_url` properties is expected.

Where you're currently using `x` (the object with the `user` property), use `x.user` instead.